# How to install the SQL 2008 R2 WMI provider

Tags: sql-server-2008, wmi

I have a C# WinForms application that queries the SQL Server WMI namespace (\Microsoft\SqlServer). With SQL Server 2005, I could install the client connectivity components to install this namespace and the WMI provider. With SQL Server 2008 R2, this does not appear to be the case. Does anyone know which SQL component (msi package) I can run to install the SQL 2008 WMI provider without having to actually install the database itself?

Comment: hav you installed SQL Native Client 10?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Management Objects, Native Client (including SDK), and CLR Types. The WMI namespace still doesn't exist.

Comment: I am using Windows XP Professional running in a Virtual PC VM.